# Saving pandas dataframe inside dynamically created folder

Tags: python, pandas

My requirement is to save a pandas dataframe as parquet inside a date folder which should be created dynamically if not present. I am having the folder names inside a list(date_folder_list), 'parquet_folder' is an existing folder. The code with which I have tried is given below. Please help -

```
for x in date_folder_list:
    print(x)
    dir = os.path.join('parquet_folder/%s' %str(x) + '/')
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
      reconcilitn_df.to_parquet(os.makedirs(dir)+'/asasass.parquet' ,engine='pyarrow',compression='snappy')
```

Error I am getting:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: change + to a , [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: No it's not working, may be because it's inside df.to_parquet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
for x in date_folder_list:
            print(x)
            dir = os.path.join('parquet/%s' %str(x))
            if not os.path.exists(dir):
                os.makedirs(dir)
                reconcilitn_df.to_parquet('parquet' + '/' + str(x) + '/' + 'Reconciliation.parquet' ,engine='pyarrow',compression='snappy')
            else :
                reconcilitn_df.to_parquet('parquet' + '/' + str(x) + '/' + 'Reconciliation.parquet' ,engine='pyarrow',compression='snappy')
```